# How to store information in Database for checkbox with single value and checkbox with multiple values in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have managed to handle the checkbox with single value by doing the below:

```
List Of Values: Static
Display Value: Lead    Return Value:Y

Source: 
Type:Database Column
Database Column: Lead1

Computation: After Submit:
Item=value
Y,
```

It does not work.

I also have a scenario where I need to deal with the multiple values of checkbox and I need help with that as well.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, a checkbox means **binary**: either it is clicked, or it is not.

If you need to have **multiple values**, then switch to Radio buttons group. It just makes more sense (at least, to me). Its setup is very similar to checkbox settings; you'd decide which number of columns you want to use with the group, set valid values ... Much easier to maintain & understand.

Answer (score 0):

When you say multiple value of checkbox do you mean multiple checkbox's within a checkbox group? If yes and you want to separate the values of those checkboxes you can do so using a query similar to this:

```
with test as
(select 'value1:value2:value3:etc:etc' col from dual) --Replace text with checkbox group page item 
select regexp_substr(col, '[^\:]+', 1, level) result
from test
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^:]+')) + 1
;
```

Because APEX stores all the active checkbox's for a group as 1 string separated by a colon, the above query will let you split them as rows (like the opposite of a LISTAGG).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I am new to apex, I want to know that in the backend(DB) we create seperate columns for as many records we have in the checkbox group value right? Also, If there is any video for the checkbox values with database online that would be of great help.

Comment: I would highly recommend you have a read through this Oracle documentation on page Items: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11947/bldapp_item.htm#HTMDB25308

This goes into detail about how the various items are used and "Referencing Item Values" section near the bottom explains how the items are passed to and from the database. After reading it the best thing to do is play around with page items in APEX and read the help tab in page designer.